# Custom to_json method not being called in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I have a Ruby on Rails application that I'm working on an API for an associated iPhone application.

I have overwritten the `to_json` method of my Item model to return some custom information from the API request that I'll need in the iPhone app.

However, when I use the built-in rails to_json method and include my Item model as an associated parameter, my `Item#to_json` method is not called, and just the default to_json on the AR object is called.

See the following code (`@api_user is a User model object`)

```
    render :json => @api_user.to_json( :include => { :friends => { :include => :items, :except => :api_token } } )
```

I'm including the `friends` association which is in turn including the `items` assocation, but the default `to_json` on Item is being called, not my custom to_json.

What am I missing?

Here is my `Item#to_json` method

```
  def to_json(options={})
{
  :id => self.id,
  :name => name,
  :description => description,
  :url => url,
  :quantity => quantity,
  :price_range_raw => price_range,
  :price_range => human_readable_price_range( price_range ),
  :can_be_purchased => can_be_purchased?,
  :completely_purchased => completely_purchased?,
  :remaining_qty => remaining_quantity,
  :thumb_photo_url => photo.url(:thumb),
  :small_photo_url => photo.url(:small),
  :large_photo_url => photo.url(:large),
  :priority_raw => priority,
  :priority => human_readable_priority( priority )
}.to_json
```

end

No other models have the `#to_json` method overriden

Comment: Can you show your `to_json` method? My initial guess is either the `to_json` method for `User` does not recursively call the `Item` one, or your `to_json` method takes different arguments and some kind of `method_missing` magic method is being called instead.

Comment: I'm digging into the source and my guess is that the ActiveSupport JSON encoder for enumerables doesnt call to_json on each item but rather serializes the whole array as one.  I'll probably have to write my own mapping function I guess to pass back the data like I want

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Devise? If so, they overwrite the to_json and to_xml method (thanks, guys).

From the Devise source:

```
  %w(to_xml to_json).each do |method|
    class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{method}(options={})
        if self.class.respond_to?(:accessible_attributes)
          options = { :only => self.class.accessible_attributes.to_a }.merge(options || {})
          super(options)
        else
          super
        end
      end
    RUBY
  end
```

Comment: this method still calls `super()` so it would still kit my custom method

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a more straightforward method to override the to_json method?  Using Devise doesn't address the general issue.  There are plenty of reasons why I might wish to choose to NOT marshal out some attributes of a particular object, thus requiring a custom method.